How could the mystery and the whole deal with Breach not be immediately obvious to foreigners?
In China Miéville's "The City and the City", the reader soon learns there are two city-states, Besźel and Ul Qoma, which coexist geographically in almost the same location. Citizens from one city are socialized from childhood to ignore the citizens from their "twin city" even though they might walking next to them, and this comes almost automatically (though not flawlessly).
There's also the Breach, a mysterious organization that polices the "border" between the two cities and deals promptly with any infractions, and whom most citizens cannot even perceive until they act on an infraction.
There's a murder mystery in the novel, and some conspiracies. Most of them require the various characters to not understand exactly what's happening, in part due to the rules of the two cities

 though of course, at least one of the conspirators does understand it perfectly: David Bowden.

Because understanding what to see/not to see for citizens of either city is a hard skill learned from childhood, this poses a problem for foreigners visiting either city. Visitors are forced to take a training course to deal with the rules of the cities, and while they are not expected to be as good as native Besź or Ul Qomans at it, they are expected to at least pretend not to see illegal things and to avoid purposefully "breaching".
However, at least some of the mystery depends on foreigners being as blind as native citizens, most noticeably

 Mahalia, the archeologist/agitator that gets murdered at the beginning of the novel. She should have known there is no Orciny (the alleged secret city) and she should also know where everyone in Breach is at any given time, since she's not blind to any it. Also her friend Yolanda and, I suppose, most of the student archeologists in the archeological dig, since none of them are natives of either city.

Why did the conspiracies/secrets work with these foreigners that weren't properly socialized to "unsee"?

i don't understand the logic. Why would anyone know where everyone in Breach is? And why should they know there is no Orciny? If they can't necessarily tell which city someone is in, how would they know that they're not in a third?

@DanielRoseman I considered this, but there's more to Orciny than simply "hiding in plain sight"; the conspiracy is also that they are supposed to be the real power. But where? Anyone not conditioned to unsee could tell that there's no such thing. (And, in fact, the person in my spoiler does figure it out! It simply takes her longer. But how on Earth was she fooled to begin with?).

As for Breach, and the whole thing in general... you may have a point. Part of Breach's power (and mysteriousness) is that people cannot see where they are until they decide to make themselves seen. But I suppose to a foreigner it'd be like being completely colorblind in a place where absolutely everything is determined according to colors: people would behave in ways you cannot understand or explain, responding to stimuli you cannot perceive.

@Andres There can be two aspects of the selective blindness learned from childhood. (1) I don't see you if you don't exhibit in-group behavior, and (2) I don't see you if you exhibit behavior I recognize as out-group.  Total outsiders are oblivious to both.  The members of a hypothetical third city could recognize each other by behavioral signals that are not recognized as "known out-group" by either Besźel or Ul Qoma, while still avoiding the breach condition by otherwise selectively adopting the behaviors of one or the other citizenry. Does this answer your question?

@Ethan Good point. Maybe! Though an alleged secret cabal that is ruling both cities (Orciny) would be harder to ignore (or ignore that you can't find them), right?

Well, there is a group of people that, while not secret, are invisible to the residents most of the time and have unusual authority: Breach. So an outsider could easily hypothesize that Orciny was a subset of Breach, or that it consisted of Breach members doing "third-city things" in their spare time.

But seeing as Miéville is known to be just a tad fond of political metaphor in his books, perhaps the best way to interpret this is metaphorically, bearing in mind that Miéville is classically and solidly left-wing: while people may try to seek a secret third power (the aliens, the Jews, the Masons, the Illuminati) to blame for their situation, there are in reality just two classes, the bourgeoisie and the proletariat, and everything that goes wrong is because of selfishness or ineptness on the part of one of them (more often the first), without any secret puppet master pulling the strings.

I.e. it's not supposed to entirely make sense, psychologically, because it's in a whole book of psychology that could only exist metaphorically in the real world.

@Adamant I agree with your three comments. Breach = Orciny is explicitly considered by at least one of the characters (then discarded, and Breach seem puzzled by the notion. They also claim Breach avatars going rogue are hunted down mercilessly... but of course, they would say that). Re: Miéville being left-wing and this being a metaphor, fully acknowledged (and it's part of why I enjoy it). That'd be an "out-of-universe" analysis though, I was considering the in-universe perspective. That said, I think you got it with your three comments indeed!

@Adamant while people may try to seek a secret third power (the aliens, the Jews, the Masons, the Illuminati) to blame for their situation, there are in reality just two classes --> this is key, an indeed, it was also my reading of the metaphorical meaning of the novel. Glad someone else also saw it :)

Breach appears to be a supernatural rather than mundane organisation.

@Valorum at some point in the novel I thought it was going to be aliens, but then Miéville gives no clear indication that's the case. Once we see Breach from Borlú's eyes, we see that [SPOILERS] at least their human avatars are former breachers caught by Breach but deemed useful (Ashil says as much; he also says once you wilfully breach there's no going back to normal life because you can never reliably unsee again). We also learn people do see Breach, it's just that they are both strongly conditioned to unsee them and they fear them (stronger urge to unsee!). Breach HQ is a mystery though.

As another example, during the unificationist riot the now aware Borlú can see panicked civilians, and among them, Breach agents ("avatars") mimicking them (until they grab someone away). So at least the agents are very good at hiding, but not using supernatural skills. Good question though, maybe it warrants a separate question!
